# Convert Coffeescript to Typescript for usage with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, coffeescript

I would like to play around with this navbar animations from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/angeal185/pen/dXmPPm?q=animated%20sidebar%20&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false)
but its using Coffeescript and im not sure how to use this. 
Is there a way to find a workaround for this or do i need to convert it into typescipt?
this is what the coffeescript looks like

```
do (window) ->
if 'classList' of document.documentElement

haClass = (elem, c) ->
  elem.classList.contains c

adClass = (elem, c) ->
  elem.classList.add c
  return

remClass = (elem, c) ->
  elem.classList.remove c
  return


anim = 
hasClass: haClass
addClass: adClass
removeClass: remClass
ha: haClass
ad: adClass
rem: remClass
if typeof define == 'function' and define.amd
define anim
else
window.anim = anim
return
menuEffects = do ->

hasParentClass = (e, classname) ->
if e == document
  return false
if anim.ha(e, classname)
  return true
e.parentNode and hasParentClass(e.parentNode, classname)

statusCheck = ->
check = false
check

init = ->
container = document.getElementById('sdcnt')
buttons = Array::slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#sd-trig > button'))
eventtype = if statusCheck() then 'touchstart' else 'click'

returnMen = ->
  anim.rem container, 'sdmenu-open'
  return

bodyClickFn = (evt) ->
  if !hasParentClass(evt.target, 'sdmenu')
    returnMen()
    document.removeEventListener eventtype, bodyClickFn
  return

buttons.forEach (el, i) ->
  effect = el.getAttribute('effect')
  el.addEventListener eventtype, (ev) ->
    ev.stopPropagation()
    ev.preventDefault()
    container.className = 'sdcnt'
    anim.ad container, effect
    setTimeout (->
      anim.ad container, 'sdmenu-open'
      return
    ), 25
    document.addEventListener eventtype, bodyClickFn
    return
  return
return

init()
return

# removable page animations
$('a').attr 'class': 'hvr-underline-from-left hvr-wobble-horizontal'
$('i').attr 'class': 'ion-ios-arrow-forward'
$('button').attr 'class': 'animated bounceIn  hvr-pulse-grow'
$('h1').attr 'class': 'animated bounceIn hvr-pulse-grow'
$('h2').attr 'class': 'animated bounceIn hvr-wobble-skew'
```

tbh im not even sure how to use this, im not familiar with it
any good advices would be appreciated!

Comment: Download the zip from codepen or look in the page source, you will find normal javascript there (transpiked from coffeescript) You can use javascript code in Angular

Comment: it does work but my angular app doesnt works as expected , no action happening

Comment: There might be a hundred reasons for that, but one mistake that is often made is that you try to manipulate the DOM manually, while Angular is keeping its own version of the DOM in memory, so that will create conflicts. It's better to use Angular's own animation system or at least tie your functions to Angular components.